# SQL Server, nvarchar(MAX) or ntext, image or varbinary?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-types

When should I choose one or the other? What are the implications regarding space and (full-text) indexing?

BTW: I'm currently using SQL Server 2005 planing to upgrade to 2008 in the following months.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new (max) fields make it a lot easier to deal with the data from .NET code.  With `varbinary(max)`, you simply set the value of a `SqlParameter` to a byte array and you are done.  WIth the image field, you need to write a few hundred lines of code to stream the data into and out of the field.

Also, the image/text fields are deprecated in favor of `varbinary(max)` and `varchar(max)`, and future versions of Sql Server will discontinue support for them.

Answer (score 4):

Once you put it in the blob, it's going to be difficult to be used for normal SQL comparison. See [Using Large-Value Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx).