# Is there a big technical difference between VARBINARY(MAX) and IMAGE data types?

Tags: image, sql-server-2008, ado.net, varbinary

I was reading on internet these statements about **SQL Server** data types:

1. `VARBINARY(MAX)` - Binary strings
   with a variable length can store up
   to 2^31-1 bytes.
2. `IMAGE` - Binary strings with a
   variable length up to 2^31-1
   (2,147,483,647) bytes.

Is there a really big technical difference between `VARBINARY(MAX)` and `IMAGE` data types?

If there is a difference: do we have to customize how ADO.NET inserts and updates image data field in SQL Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They store the same data: this is as far as it goes.

"`image`" is deprecated and has a limited set of features and operations that work with it. `varbinary(max)` can be operated on like shorter `varbinary` (ditto for `text` and `varchar(max)`).

Do not use `image` for any new project: just search here for the issues folk have with `image` and `text` datatypes because of the limited functionality.

Examples from SO: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203/sql-server-nvarcharmax-or-ntext-image-or-varbinary), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820374/sql-server-table-structure-for-storing-a-large-number-of-images)

Comment: Limitation of VARBINARY(MAX): Partial updates are not supported on columns that have a FILESTREAM as a source. [(tekkies.co.uk)](http://wiki.tekkies.co.uk/Porting_SQL_IMAGE_to_VARBINARY(MAX))

Answer (score 7):

I think that technically they are similar, but it is important to notice the following from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.
>
> Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and Unicode character and >binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2 character set.

Answer (score 5):

> They store the same data: this is as far as it goes.
>
> "image" is deprecated and has a limited set of features and operations
>   that work with it. varbinary(max) can be operated on like shorter
>   varbinary (ditto for text and varchar(max)).
>
> Do not use image for any new project: just search here for the issues
>   folk have with image and text datatypes because of the limited
>   functionality.

In fact, `VARBINARY` can store any data that can be converted into a byte array, such as files, and this is the same process that `IMAGE` data type uses, so, by this point of view, both data types can store the same data.
But `VARBINARY` have a size property, while `IMAGE` accepts any size up to the data type limits, so when using `IMAGE` data type, you will spend more resources to store the same data. 
In a **Microsoft® SQL Server®**, the `IMAGE` data type is really deprecated, then you must bet in `VARBINARY` data type.

But be carefull: **The Microsoft® SQL Server® CE®** (including the latest 4.0 version) still using `IMAGE` data type and probably this data type will not "disappears" so soon, because in Compact Edition versions, this data type is better than any other to fast files storage.

Answer (score 0):

I inadvertently found one difference between them. You can insert a string into an image type but not into a varbinary. Maybe that's why MS is deprecating the image type as it really doesn't make sense to set an image with a string.

Comment: According to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream it is really possible to save it, and it is even using it for testing, and also it is possible to read the text directly in the file, which might be great for testing, so I don't see a difference as long as you the required casts, and of course thee is usage for strings not just for testing but also for saving text based articles (though the correct naming for this is not "Image")