# How is better save and load a picture on c# (asp.net) and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, varbinary

I want to save pictures, and show them in a gridview with the name, description, price, and other things, but I don't know how to do it. First, how should I upload the image? I'm currently using a Windows Forms application to save the other information, but I now need to save the image as well.  These images will need to be viewed from a web page in an ASP.NET application.

I don't think I need to save the path, because other users will be loading it via the web page on their computer. What's the best format to use in the database `varbinary` or `image`. I'm not sure how to use these or how to make them visible in the gridview. I do know how to do it if I have the path to the image, but not if the image is in the database.

Can anyone show me how to store the image in a database then display it in a gridview?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question as written gave me a headache. Even if English isn't your first language please take the time to lay out your question in a logical and coherent manner if you expect quality answers.

Comment: for an explanation of the difference between varbinary and image, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113294/is-there-a-big-technical-difference-between-varbinarymax-and-image-data-types/4113417#4113417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store it in the database, you should use `varbinary`.  It's functionally equivalent to the `image` column type, but `image` has been deprecated in favor of `varbinary(MAX)`.  Typically, to use the image from the database you'd create an HttpHandler (or a controller/action if using ASP.NET MVC) that handles a url encoding the identifier associated with the image, for example, `http://www.example.com/imagehandler.ashx?id=42`.  The handler, in this case, would know to find the image with id `42` in the database and construct a response from the byte array corresponding to the columns contents with the correct MIME type.

Sample code: **completely untested**

```
public class ImageHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
         int imageID = -1;
         if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] == null || !int.TryParse( context.Request.QueryString["id"], out imageID) ) 
         {
             throw new ArgumentException("Invalid or missing image id.");
         }

         using (var context = new ImagesDataContext())
         {
              var image = context.Images.SingleOrDefault( i => i.ID == imageID );
              if (image != null)
              {
                   context.Response.ContentType = image.MimeType;
                   context.Response.BinaryWrite( image.Content );
              }
              else
              {
                  // decide how you want to handle an image that isn't found
              }
         }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    } 
}
```