# I want to save an image from my C# form application to SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to save an image from my C# form application to SQL Server Database, currently i m doing this:
In class library class named PhotoCL:

```
public void AddPhoto(int id, Image  photo)
    {
        db.ExecuteNonQuery("spAddPhoto", new object[] { id, photo});
    }
```

"spAddPhoto" is the stored Procedure which have 2 parameters, @id `int`, @img `image`
In database the table of photos also have two columns with same data types as mentioned above in SP.

This is the Code behind my AddPhoto Button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mp.AddPhoto(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue),pictureBox1.Image);
    }
```

I m getting this error at runtime(Debugging):

> *"Failed to convert parameter value from a Bitmap to a Byte[]."*

Please help me out.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you absolutely positively need to save images to the database?

Comment: Why make it a mystery novel and leave the interesting code out? What is `db.ExecuteNonQuery` doing?

Comment: Convert the image to byte first. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880213/saving-an-image-file-to-sql-server-and-converting-byte-array-into-image?rq=1

Comment: @Remus you can say it as Connection String. I write this code in the begining of every of my Class Library's Class.

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConStr");

ConStr is the Connection string of database which is written in an Application Configuration File.

Comment: I m using the Classes of Enterprise Library.

Comment: Please Correct my Code :( anyone please. .

Answer (score 0):

You don't insert an image like this to a database, you should insert a flow of byte corresponding to the image.

Would [this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020929.asp) be of help ?

Comment: Please Correct my Code :(
anyone please. .

Comment: You're giving us 2 lines of code... it's not correction you need, it's coding. Maybe also this article can help ? http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server/105-store-save-images-in-sql-server.html