# insert an image into a database c#

Tags: c#, sql, image, blob

So I have this code:

```
if ((uplImage.FileName != ""))
{
    byte[] raw = new byte[10000];

    //to allow only jpg gif and png files to be uploaded.
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(uplImage.PostedFile.FileName.ToUpper());
    if (((extension == ".JPG") || ((extension == ".GIF") || (extension == ".PNG"))))
    {

        DALBio bio = new DALBio();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(uplImage.PostedFile.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
        fs.Read(raw, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        bio.PlayerID = Session["playerID"].ToString();
        bio.Pending = 'Y';
        bio.Photo = raw;
        DALBio.insertImage(bio);
    }
}
```

When I try this, the stream is not reading the image. `raw` never gets the image. It stays empty and it gets caught when it executes the stored procedure, saying I never passed the image. I am confident that code is just fine. I do not know why I can't get the image into my byte array.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Are you sure 10000 bytes is enough? I tried it and it works fine. Had to boost the bytes up to 400 000 for my small test picture.

Comment: Consider storing a filename reference to the file in the db, and store the actual file elsewhere.

Comment: my image is actually just 60 bytes big,  when i tried to just say byte [] raw  and then a few liens later use raw, it just skipped over raw.  so thats why i gave it a size and instantiated it earlier

Comment: Also a similar question that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880213/saving-an-image-file-to-sql-server-and-converting-byte-array-into-image?rq=1

Comment: Any reason you can't use `var raw = System.File.IO.ReadAllBytes(uplImage.PostedFile.FileName)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create/define the `raw` array as

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(uplImage.PostedFile.FileName, 
                         FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                          FileShare.Read);

    raw = new byte[fs.Length]; 

// same code as above..
```

You can also try similar code

```
        System.IO.Stream myStream;
        Int32 fileLen;

        // Get the length of the file.
        fileLen = uplImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;  


        // Create a byte array to hold the contents of the file.
        Byte[] input = new Byte[fileLen];

        // Initialize the stream to read the uploaded file.
        myStream = uplImage.FileContent;

        // Read the file into the byte array.
        myStream.Read(input, 0, fileLen); 
        // input will hold the byte array
```

Comment: forwhatever reason, using this example works.  not i just have to convert from varchar to varbinary as my stored proc doesnt like the implicit conversion

Comment: Code is from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I get the `ByteArray`:

```
public Byte[] GetArrayFromFile(string path)
{
  Byte[] data = null;

  FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(path);
  long numBytes = fileInf.Length;

  using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(fStream);

    data = bReader.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Then it stores in the database correctly using Entity Framework (it should be working if your `DAL` inserts your objects correctly in the database).

Comment: Also note `FileStream` is `IDisposable`, so you might want to dispose of it or put it in a `using` block.

Comment: this still gives me the same problem.  using the code in the answer provided, data stays at a size of 0, nothing gets written to it.