# How to insert image from image control into WPF to SQL Database using entity data model

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

i am creating an app to save student information into SQL , I want to know how to insert image from image control in WPF using entity framework to SQL database

i made event to upload image into image control and now i need to save it to sql database using entity framework

image load button code :

```
private void uploadbt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
     op.Title = "Select a picture";
     op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
         "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
         "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
     if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
         photo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
     }  
 }
```

this is my database named cv

[image]

this is my code to save some information into database this cose for save button

```
facultymakerEntities1 entity = new  facultymakerEntities1();

         cv CV = new cv();
         CV.Full_Name = fullnametb.Text;
         CV.Activities = activitestb.Text;
         CV.Address = addresstb.Text;
         CV.Birth_Day = bddate.SelectedDate.Value;
         CV.Courses = cousetb.Text;
         CV.E_Mail = emailtb.Text;

         entity.cvs.Add(CV);
         entity.SaveChanges();
```

how can i save image from image control into database ?

thanks;

Comment: [dont use image for sql server data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113294/is-there-a-big-technical-difference-between-varbinarymax-and-image-data-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will most certainly store an encoded image as `byte[]`. The following method creates a PNG frame from a BitmapSource:

```
private byte[] BitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or some other encoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As you put BitmapImages to your Image's Source, you may simply pass that to this method:

```
var imageBuffer = BitmapSourceToByteArray((BitmapSource)photo.Source);
```

Answer (score 2):

Image in SqlServer is "Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes". In EF you need to have a property of `byte[]` type which can be mapped to a column of `image` type in SqlServer. When you load your image from disk don't load it to the BitmapImage but to a byte array, set the property accordingly and `.SaveChanges()` to store it in the database. If you want to show the image to the user load it from the database as byte array and then create a BitmapImage instance. You probably would have to use `BimatpImage.StreamSource` property to do that.