# MVC EF Insert bitmap into table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, graphics, bitmap

After an edit, this code generates a bitmap and writes it to a hdd file. How do I save this in my db?

```
//   first   save the edit data  
Actionresult Edit (Lot Lot)   
{    remove scaffold code for clarity
db.SaveChanges();
// create a new image to replace image currently in db.  
Bitmap mybmp = new Bitmap(400, 20);  
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mybmp);  
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 400, 20);  
SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.OldLace);  
g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, 400, 20);  
// write a test file to confirm this is ok   ------it works  
mybmp.Save("C:\\temp\\lot1.bmp",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

//  add code here to save image to Lot table field TaskImage  here
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

My class:

```
public class Lot
{
public int LotID { get; set; }
public byte?[] TaskImage { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880164/how-to-insert-image-from-image-control-into-wpf-to-sql-database-using-entity-dat

Comment: The 2nd answer in your reference seems to be the solution, but I don't know how to code it. @Pawel

Comment: Are you using CodeFirst or the EF Designer?

Answer (score 0):

From the EF perspective the model would look like this:

```
public class PhotoContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<PhotoEntity> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

This will map the `Image` property that is a byte array to a column of `image` type in the database. To convert an image to/from the byte array you should be able to use something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv). If you set the `Image` property to a result of the conversion method and call `.SaveChanges()` it will save your image to the database. When you query the database the materialized entities will have the `Image` property set to data from the database and you will have to convert them back to get the image.